# How to fetch columns from joined table in Kohana 2.x

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

I'm using kohana 2.x for my project,I've following query

```
 $result = ORM::factory('table1')
                        ->join('table2','table1.id','table2.id')
                        ->find_all();
```

Using above query I can fetch data from table1,but I need fetch data from table2 also.When I'm giving like this

```
$result->table2_column_name;
```

It showing error,how can I fetch the data from table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is neither ORM or Active Record. If you have a `Table1_Model` class that extends `ORM` class then you can use `ORM::factory('table1');` You also need almost same thing for table2. And for each class there should be relations declared. <sup>[Getting Started with ORM](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm/starting)</sup>

The resultant models will be,

```
class Table1_Model extends ORM {
    protected $has_one = array('table2');
}

class Table2_Model extends ORM {
    protected $has_one = array('table1');
}
```

Now you can query like this,

```
$result = ORM::factory('table1', 1);
echo $result->table1_column_name;
echo $result->table2->table2_column_name;
```

Comment: Its working now,thanks for your answer.Where I can find the documents to learn Kohana ORM other than Kohana own documentation

Comment: Kohana 2x had a small sized community. So I didn't find anything helpful. The documentation is quite good. Also try to generate documentation from the kohana source by phpdoc or something. This will be a good source of api doc.